# Error: 'User' object has no attribute 'exists' on Heroku url, but works on local host url

Tags: django, sqlite, heroku, django-rest-framework, django-views

So I am trying to request the logged in user, from the Heroku url, but gives me the error 'User' object has no attribute 'exists'. Whenever I try to do the exact same task, but on my local host url, I get the user and everything works perfectly. I think the issue roots from my database being out of synce, but I ran python3 manage.py makemigrations and migrate, but that didn't change anything.

Also on a related note, when I try to sign into the admin with my super user, it works on the local host but not on Heroku. I know it's because it also doesn't think the superuser exist.

I was going to change my Database, to mysqlite to postgresql, with the hopes of that fixing it, because that was already on the todo list for my full stack, but I want to figure out why this is happening before moving forward.

If anyone could help that would be fantastic.

Comment: You say: "I ran python3 manage.py makemigrations and migrate", did you do so on your computer or on Heroku? From your wording I pick up on that you're only running your migrations locally

Comment: I just ran heroku run python manage.py migrate, and it still didn't work.

Comment: Actually that made it work on my Postman, but not on Swagger, and it didn't fix logging into admin on Heroku, but that's a good enough step for me, thank you!!